# Add token for message template in nopCommerce

Tags: nopcommerce

I'm working on nopCommerce and I want to send an email to
customer using message template. I made a message template. Here is
a screenshot but **when I send an email then its printing the direct string not
replacing its actual value**. Can someone help for that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I added the token inside my
`Libraries\Nop.Services\Messages\MessageTokenProvider.cs` and also my
message template

Added on message template in backend

```
Customer Number:
%Order.CustomerNumber%
<br /> 
affilate Number:
%Order.AffilateNumber%
```

Libraries\Nop.Services\Messages\MessageTokenProvider.cs

```
tokens.Add(new Token("Order.PurchaseOrderNumber", order.CustomerNumber));
tokens.Add(new Token("Order.ReferenceNumber", order.AffilateNumber));
```